# Перегрузка функции в TypeScript

Tags: javascript, функции, typescript, function-overloading

```
interface MyPosition {
    x: number|undefined
    y: number|undefined
}

interface MyPositionDefault extends MyPosition {
    z: string
}

function position(): MyPosition
function position(a: number): MyPositionDefault //Ошибка This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.
function position(a: number,b: number): MyPosition

function position(a?: number,b?: number) {
    if(!a && !b){
        return {x: undefined, y: undefined}  // {x: 'string', y: true}
    }

    if(a && !b){
        return {x: a, y:undefined, z: 'error'}
    }

    return {x: a, y: b}
}

console.log(position())
console.log(position(1))
console.log(position(1, 2))
```

Валидатор выдает ошибку на вторую перегрузку.
Кроме того, в return можно возвращать объекты с любым типом. Ошибки наоборот не выдает.

Comment: Какую версию typescript используете? На версии 3.2.2 данной ошибки нету.

Comment: Что бы ts проверял на возвращаем тип, надо в имплементации указать возвращаемый тип, например `: MyPosition | MyPositionDefault`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8AKB7AzsMYbEZAbwChlkAPALmRAFcBbAI2mQB9lGQATCDFAQ+AbkrJ09Jmw7deAoSBHiAvuXKhIsRCgw58hYgBFBcRgBswyCNUj9caLHgJESFKgC96uMFFAA5moaMLwIRiQADi4RABQAlPT6MW7ioSDhbsjRhm6xcNIs7FCJTgauJmaWYGlhEdkpxPmFslAANMisLcWlybnE4uTpmcQN-SD5APzd0B2s0wxF0L3O41xljSCm8NVUHsjAMMixAIRwyABkF8gnrPFkElRQEGCMUO6PVDT0CoLCfG1PlQpDx+H9lHxPqpRFQAPSwsh0ZAAcl8-hAAWRHRBfkYEHUVHUEkOx3OVxudweX2Qz1e7yp1O+yDggMZkh+YKUIlZjO8KOgUGwUGRUPEhI0Txebw+1KRLM+INYEmh5CJCGIuGwFggADoLNgArEchUJvF4uJ1SBNdq9QajZtYgBGM0WjVa3X6w3GuKOjoAJhdQA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо было указать тип, который возвращает имплементация.

[Пример](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8AKB7AzsMYbEZAbwChlkAPALmRAFcBbAI2mQB9lGQATCDFAQ+AbkrJ09Jmw7deAoSBHiAvuXKhIsRCgw58hYgBFBcRgBswyCNUj9caLHgJESFKgC96uMFFAA5moaMLwIRiQADi4RABQAlPT6MW7ioSDhbsjRhm6xcNIs7FCJTgauJmaWYGlhEdkpxPmFslAANMisLcWlybnE4uTpmcQN-SD5APzd0B2s0wxF0L3O41xljSCm8NVUHsjAMMixAIRwyABkF8gnrPFkElRQEGCMUO6PVDT0CoLCfG1PlQpDx+H9lHxPqpRFQAPSwsh0ZAAcl8-hAAWRHRBfkYEHUVHUEkOx3OVxudweX2Qz1e7yp1O+yDggMZkh+YKUIlZjO8KOgUGwUGRUPEhI0Txebw+1KRLM+INYEmh5CJCGIuGwFggADoLNgArEchUJvF4uJ1SBNdq9QajZtYgBGM0WjVa3X6w3GuKOjoAJhdQA)

```
interface MyPosition {
  x: number | undefined;
  y: number | undefined;
}

interface MyPositionDefault extends MyPosition {
  z: string;
}

function position(): MyPosition;
function position(a: number): MyPositionDefault;
function position(a: number, b: number): MyPosition;

function position(a?: number, b?: number): MyPosition | MyPositionDefault  {
  if (!a && !b) {
    return {
      x: undefined,
      y: undefined
    };  // {x: 'string', y: true}
  }

  if (a && !b) {
    return {
      x: a,
      y: undefined,
      z: 'error'
    };
  }

  return {
    x: a,
    y: b
  };
}

console.log(position());
console.log(position(1));
console.log(position(1, 2));
```